# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException when getting player stats

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

I'm storing player stats for my minigame in a SQL database and I'm getting the following error while loading stats:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1187)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1182)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4035)
[23:37:09] [Server thread/WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4004)
```

Code:

```java
public void loadPlayer(Player p) {
    if (!isPlayerInDataBase(p)) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (Connection connection = sqlConnection.c) {
                    PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO `MurderData` (uuid, wins, deaths, loses, kills, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    insert.setString(1, p.getUniqueId().toString());
                    insert.setInt(2, 0);
                    insert.setInt(3, 0);
                    insert.setInt(4, 0);
                    insert.setInt(5, 0);
                    insert.setInt(6, 0);
                    insert.execute();
                    ClosePreparedStatement(insert);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (isPlayerInDataBase(p)) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (Connection connection = sqlConnection.c;
                     PreparedStatement select = connection.prepareStatement(
                             "SELECT * FROM `MurderData` WHERE uuid='" + p.getUniqueId().toString() + "'")) {
                    ResultSet result = select.executeQuery();
                    if (result.next()) {
                        if (getPlayerData(p) != null) {
                            getPlayerData(p).adddeaths(result.getInt("deaths"));
                            getPlayerData(p).addkill(result.getInt("kills"));
                            getPlayerData(p).addwins(result.getInt("wins"));
                            getPlayerData(p).addlose(result.getInt("loses"));
                            getPlayerData(p).addscore(result.getInt("score"));
                        }
                        CloseResultSet(result);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error at this code:

```java
PreparedStatement select = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT * FROM `MurderData` WHERE uuid='" + p.getUniqueId().toString() + "'")) {
```

Full code:

```java
public boolean isPlayerInDataBase(Player p) {
    try (Connection connection = sqlConnection.c;
         PreparedStatement select = connection.prepareStatement(
                 "SELECT * FROM `MurderData` WHERE uuid='" + p.getUniqueId().toString() + "'")) {
        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            result.close();
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Side question: should I close the result set and prepared statements after completing the process? And should I do that instantly or with a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have taken the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement from some other code without understanding what it does. From that link:

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

In other words, when you use the syntax

```
try (Connection connection = sqlConnection.c) {
     // ...
}
```

You are implicitly calling [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--) on `sqlConnection.c`, which is not assigned to again. Therefore, the next time you try to query your database from this connection, it is still closed, so you get this error.

A simple fix would be to move the declaration of local variable `connection` out of the try-with-resources statement so it does not get closed at the end of the method. You should also look at where you use the try-with-resources syntax elsewhere in your program and make sure you're not closing anything you don't want to close.

This is the fixed version of your code (from the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/dKMLuaCB) you linked in a comment):

```java
public boolean isPlayerInDataBase(Player p) {
    Connection connection = sql.getConnection();
    try (PreparedStatement select = connection.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * FROM `MurderData` WHERE uuid='" + p.getUniqueId().toString() + "'")) {

        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            CloseResultSet(result);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Additionally, in your `loadPlayer()` method, you can replace the two `if` statements with this:

```
if (isPlayerInDataBase(p)) {
    // code if player is in database
} else {
    // code if player is not in database
}
```

Comment: One more question should I close prepared statements and result sets after updating data? and when should i close it i mean like after like 5 seconds is that fine? or i should not close them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `isPlayerInDataBase` call closes the connection. And in the line where your error occurs, you are using that *same connection* that you closed.

This is why you are getting the error you see, because you are attempting to perform a database operation after the connection is closed.

Comment: This is my current code: https://pastebin.com/dKMLuaCB, it closes the resut set after 3 seconds, i tried removing the close connection but it didnt work either.